# 3-handle cancellation of 4-dimensional handlebody.

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 4-manifolds

Let $X^4$ be the 4-dimensional handlebody with $\partial X=S^3$ and $\pi_i(X)=\pi_i(B^4)$.

Is it true that we can always change $X^4$ with handlebody without 3-handle?

(I'm concerning about the Andrews-Curtis conjecture)

Comment: What kind of "change" do you want to allow?  For example, do you allow replacing $X$ with a 4-ball?  That would do it. 

Comment: Are you allowing handle slides?  Cancellations? Perhaps more or less? 

Comment: Fixing diffeomorphism type.

Comment: Allowing handle slide and cancellation. 

Comment: A little confused -- is John Smith the same person as Topologieee? 